# ClassCastException on layoutInflater.inflate(...)

Tags: android, adapter, layout-inflater

I keep getting the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
```

Whenever the following is executed:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(mLinearLayout);
}
```

When makes no sense because this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/item_text_view"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thus the root of the XML file should be LinearLayout, so the inflater should return LinearLayout, where is it getting FrameLayout?

Comment: Is this the xml of a  file called `item` in the layout folder?

Comment: Yes, it is. [15chars]

Comment: Why do you need to cast? Just use `View v = inflater.inflate`

Comment: Look: `.inflate(R.layout.item..)`, but your LinearLayout has no id, so try assigning it to `item`

Comment: You have no child with the id `item` in your layout

Comment: @cricket_007 the ViewHolder's constructor expects a linear layout. Yes, it needs a linear layout and not a view.

Comment: @AbAppletic It's a layout file, R.layout.item, so the lookup is by filename.

Comment: Please show the full code. The ViewHolder shouldn't need any Layout parameters that a LinearLayout would contain.

Comment: maybe you have one more item.xml in any other folder. for testing rename this xml file to my_list_item and use R.layout.my_list_item

Comment: Why would your `ViewHolder` need a `LinearLayout`? What's wrong with `View`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
return new ViewHolder(mLinearLayout);
```

By

```
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
return new ViewHolder(view);
```

EDIT

The public constructor of `ViewHolder` expects a `View` not a `LinearLayout`. If you need to access a child of this layout, like the `LinearLayout` you have to access it's from findViewById, for example:

Your Item Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/your_linear_layout_id"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/item_text_view"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Your ViewHolder

```
public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.your_linear_layout_id);
    }
}
```

onCreateViewHolder

```
 @Override
 public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
   return new ViewHolder(view);
 }
```

Comment: Read the comments above. Seems that the LinearLayout may be necessary